# How to create an empty MVC 5 project in VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm using VS2013. After searching online for a while, I learned that I could create an MVC 5 project by clicking File--New--New Project--Web--ASP.NET Web Application, then select MVC as the template. But it created a whole new website template in this way. I'm new to MVC, I just want an empty MVC 5 to learn it step by step, but I didn't find this option. How to create an empty MVC 5 project in VS2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose the ASP.NET Web application to be created, you are provided with an option to select the Empty project instead of ASP.NET MVC template. Note that an Empty ASP.NET project template can be converted to ASP.NET MVC by adding

1. **Model-view-controller** code
2. Start up registers
3. Routing schemes
4. other required ASP.NET MVC stuff...

This would allow you to have an *empty project*. What you have right now is also an empty project in a way that there is nothing added to it other than the required code and libraries.

To continue, learn ASP.NET MVC from [official website](http://www.asp.net/mvc). I also have [an article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/871375/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-using-real-world-example) written for beginners.

Comment: Thank you, I found it :)